# nginx not caching wordpress site

Tags: nginx, cache, wordpress

I have a website set up to use nginx caching. Here are the details:

```
    fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    set $no_cache 0;

    if ($request_method = POST)
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    if ($query_string != "")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $no_cache 1;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    if ($http_cookie = "PHPSESSID")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }


    root /var/www/websites/headstuff.org;
    index index.php;
    server_name _; 


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ 
    {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires 365d; #max;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) 
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; # Only GET and HEAD methods apply
        add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;


        # Regular PHP-FPM stuff:
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
           return 404;
        }
   }
}
```

But when I try

```
curl -X GET -I headstuff.org
```

I get the following

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 10:48:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d22f1949b207c61fa8f304a6be8d01e4a1454669298; expires=Sat, 04-Feb-17 10:48:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.headstuff.org; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location: http://www.headstuff.org/
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=03eubavpjg3ct5tsiu1g2eqi63; path=/
Vary: Cookie
X-Fastcgi-Cache: MISS
X-Pingback: http://www.headstuff.org/xmlrpc.php
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 26fe0acb87752999-DUB
```

Which always says X-Fastcgi-Cache: MISS

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: As far as I can see, the site is doing what you tell it to. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I'm telling the site to do. But what I would like it to do is serve up cached versions of the site with an expire of an hour.

Comment: In that case‚ setting `$no_cache` to 1 is probably not the right thing to do.

Comment: @Qwerty.ie Why haven't you tested the `if` blocks one by one to figure out which one of them is behaving differently from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

First, you configured nginx to not cache 301 redirect responses. If you want to cache these, (and you should!) then set it up:

```
fastcgi_cache_valid 301 30d;
```

Second, WordPress sent explicit instructions to not cache the redirect, so it would not be cached anyway.

Comment: I've added that in and update the files according to this http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx
Now I'm getting X-Fastcgi-Cache: EXPIRED

Comment: Of course you are. Didn't you read my last paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

You CURL'd the wrong URL, add the www. When you do that the cache works and you can see it in the headers.

Add these lines to your file to change your caching slightly.

```
# Determines in which cases a stale cached response can be used when an error occurs during
# communication with the FastCGI server
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;

# Wordpress themes (especially Photocrati) often send back inappropriate headers, so ignore them
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

I also do a bunch of header rewriting because my theme sets headers really badly.